# Make the 'Technologies' tag editor multi-line

Tags: feature-request, design, jobs

Editing the tags is a bit awkward when there are more than a few.

> [image: screenshot of read view]
>
> [image: screenshot of edit view]

Can you make the editor multi-line?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302682/1415038